# Phone number is not displaying in $formcontent of my PHP code

Tags: php

```
<?php
                 $Name = $_POST['Name'];
                 $Email = $_POST['Email'];
                 $Number= $_POST['Number'];
                 $Message= $_POST['Message'];
                 $formcontent="
                     Name: $Name \n
                     Number: $Number \n
                     Email: $Email \n
                     Message: $Message";
                 $recipient = "info@domain.com";
                 $subject = "Contact Form";
                 $mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
                 mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or               die("Error!");
                 echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

The `number` is not displaying but `name`, `email`, `message` are displaying in `formcontent`. Empty space is showing in place of number while execution.

san.

Comment: Show us your code so we can identify where you are pointing out us

Comment: It's simple your $_POST['Number'] is empty . that means either your form is submitted with empty value or the name of the text field in your form used for taking phone number not having name "Number".

Comment: You can post full HTML form...

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the value of $_POST['Number']. If it's still an empty string, then there must be a problem on the process of fetching the data via post method or in your HTML field for Number.